# Understanding memory management issue when using hana::compose with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, smart-pointers, boost-hana

Given

- a `makeDocument` function creating a temporary resource and handing it over via `std::share_ptr`,
- a `deref` function that encapsulates the application of the default `*` operator,
- and a consumer `print` function,
- [`boost::hana::compose`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/d3634a3e9ce49a2207bd7870407c05e74ce29ef5/include/boost/hana/functional/compose.hpp)

I've noticed that

```cpp
compose(print, deref, makeDocument)("good");          // OK
compose(print, compose(deref, makeDocument))("bad");  // UB
```

and I'd like to understand why. Specifically, why does the latter expression result in the temporary `std::shared_ptr` handed to `deref` to be destroyed before its pointee is handed to and processed by `print`? Why doesn't this happen in the former expression?

([CompilerExplorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/8jEjzzqKh).)

---

[I've managed to strip `hana::compose` down to the minimum I need for my example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y1dz8K54P):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename G>
struct compose {
    F f; G g;
    compose(F f, G g) : f{f}, g{g} {}

    template <typename X>
    decltype(auto) operator()(X const& x) const& {
        return f(g(x));
    }
};

struct Document {
    std::string str;
    Document(std::string&& str) : str{std::move(str)} {}
    ~Document() {
        str = "bad";
    };
};

void print(Document const& doc1) {
    std::cout << doc1.str << std::endl;
}

auto deref = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) {
    return *std::forward<decltype(x)>(x);
};

auto makeDocument = [](std::string&& str) {
    return std::make_shared<Document>(std::move(str));
};

const auto good = compose(compose(print, deref), makeDocument);
const auto bad = compose(print, compose(deref, makeDocument));

int main() {
    good("good");
    bad("good");
}
```

---

(The question was originally much longer. Look at the history to see where it comes from.)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an issue of lifetime extension. The relevant quote from the standard is here:

> [**[class.temporary]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary)
>
> 6 The temporary object to which the
> reference is bound or the temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference
> is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference if the glvalue to which the reference is bound was obtained
> through one of the following:
>
> - a temporary materialization conversion (7.3.4),
> - [...]
> - a class member access (7.6.1.4) using the . operator where the left operand is one of these expressions
>   and the right operand designates a non-static data member of non-reference type,
> - [...]
>
> The exceptions to this lifetime rule are:
>
> - A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (7.6.1.2) persists until the
>   completion of the full-expression containing the call.
> - [...]
> - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (8.7.3) is not
>   extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.

With this, your example can be further boiled down to the following snippet ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GGPhTKMoa)):

```
auto&& good = std::make_shared<Document>("good");
std::cout<<(*good).str<<std::endl;

auto&& bad = *std::make_shared<Document>("good");
std::cout<<bad.str<<std::endl;
```

In the upper block, `good` is an rvalue reference to the shared pointer and therefore does extend the lifetime until the call of `std::cout` (or in your example, for the whole execution of `compose(print, deref)`).

On the other hand, `bad` is a reference to a reference returned by the member function `operator*`, which leads to the immediate destruction of the `shared_ptr` according to the last bullet point in the quote above.

Note that if there was a member of shared_ptr which could be explicitly bound to a reference (e.g. something like `auto&& r = std::make_shared<Document>("good").wrapped_pointer`), lifetime extension would apply again. Those things are further explained in [this article](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/11/16/lifetime-extension-tidbit/), where it is explicitly adviced *against* using such constructs which depend on lifetime extension. In your example, this could be simply cured by returning *by-value* from `deref`.

Comment: +1, but I've still some difficulty in mapping my code to your snippet. I'll need more time to understand it.

Comment: @Enlico: Yes, same for me, it's tricky. I think the whole point is that due to lifetime-extension, the composition is not associative, because adding in another perfectly-forwarded identity function with `*make_shared<Document>("good")` inside spoils the lifetime-extension (as explicitly mentioned in the standard). [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/br7TPTfPK) is another incarnation without the shared_ptr.